Issue with Polylang on user profile page
I have an online store on WooCommerce with two languages, Russian (RU) and Ukrainian (UA), and plugins Polylang and LearnPress.
When I am on the ‘personal account’ page, on the left side I have links: ‘Courses’, ‘Orders’, ‘Settings’, ‘Logout’. Clicking on these links works fine and everything displays correctly until I switch to the other language. Then I am redirected to the personal account page in the corresponding language where all labels are in the appropriate language, but the links on the left side do not work correctly.
The link descriptions change according to the selected language, but the links themselves do not change and remain the same as they were before the language switch. For example, if I have RU language selected and I enter the personal account and switch to UA language, I will be on a page with labels in UA language, but the links still lead to pages with RU language content.
When I go to LearnPress General -> Profile Page settings and change the profile page to the Ukrainian language variant, the same issue occurs. When I am on the ‘profile’ page with UA language and switch the language to RU, the labels are in Russian, but the links lead to pages with Ukrainian content.
Both versions of the ‘Profile’ page have the same shortcode [learn_press_profile]: UA: https://www.smarticle.pro/wp-admin/post.php?post=9428&action=edit RU: https://www.smarticle.pro/wp-admin/post.php?post=10159&action=edit
I don’t know what to change and I think this is incorrect plugin behavior because I haven’t found the necessary settings.
If you need login and password for access, I will send them to you via email.
The page I need help with: https://www.smarticle.pro/ru/profil/

Finally i added javascript code in the footer of the page.
This script checks the current language on the page, then iterates through all links and replaces the href tag with the correct one.

To help make your answer more helpful to future readers, could you edit your answer and provide an example of the JavaScript code you used along with any other instructions to assist readers?
